# Flatten parsed xml conent in clojure using core.match

Tags: xml, clojure, pattern-matching

Consider the following xml:

```xml
      <Period>
        <TimeInterval v="2010-06-20T21:00Z/2010-06-21T21:00Z"/>
        <Resolution v="HOURLY"/>
        <AccountInterval>
            <Pos v="1"/>
            <InQty v="0.0"/>
        </AccountInterval>
        <AccountInterval>
            <Pos v="2"/>
            <InQty v="0.0"/>
        </AccountInterval>
        <AccountInterval>
            <Pos v="3"/>
            <InQty v="0.0"/>
        </AccountInterval>
    </Period>
```

I want to "flatten" the data structure returned after parsing the XML with `clojure.xml/parse`:

```clj
{:content
 [{:content nil,
   :attrs {:v "2015-06-20T21:00Z/2015-06-21T21:00Z"},
   :tag :TimeInterval}
  {:content nil, :attrs {:v "PT1H"}, :tag :Resolution}
  {:content
   [{:content nil, :attrs {:v "1"}, :tag :Pos}
    {:content nil, :attrs {:v "0.0"}, :tag :InQty}],
   :attrs nil,
   :tag :AccountInterval}
  {:content
   [{:content nil, :attrs {:v "2"}, :tag :Pos}
    {:content nil, :attrs {:v "0.0"}, :tag :InQty}],
   :attrs nil,
   :tag :AccountInterval}
  {:content
   [{:content nil, :attrs {:v "3"}, :tag :Pos}
    {:content nil, :attrs {:v "0.0"}, :tag :InQty}],
   :attrs nil,
   :tag :AccountInterval}],
 :attrs nil,
 :tag :Period}
```

to get a vector of the sort:

```clj
["2010-06-20T21:00Z/2010-06-21T21:00Z" "HOURLY" 1 0.0 2 0.0 3 0.0]
```

How can I do that using core.match in clojure?

Comment: And why do you want to use `core.match`? It doesn't look like a good tool for you task.

Comment: {:tag :Period, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :TimeInterval, :attrs {:v "2015-06-20T21:00Z/2015-06-21T21:00Z"}, :content nil} {:tag :Resolution, :attrs {:v "PT1H"}, :content nil} {:tag :AccountInterval, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :Pos, :attrs {:v "1"}, :content nil} {:tag :InQty, :attrs {:v "0.0"}, :content nil}]} {:tag :AccountInterval, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :Pos, :attrs {:v "2"}, :content nil} {:tag :InQty, :attrs {:v "0.0"}, :content nil}]} {:tag :AccountInterval, :attrs nil, :content [{:tag :Pos, :attrs {:v "3"}, :content nil} {:tag :InQty, :attrs {:v "0.0"}, :content nil}]}]}

Comment: no particular reason to use core.match. I just thought it would be interesting as an exercise. Any alternative is welcomed. Why is it not a good tool for the task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a very simple recursive function:

```clj
(defn flatten-xml
  [{:keys [attrs content]}]
  (if-let [v (:v attrs)]
    [v]
    (mapcat flat-xml content)))
```

So, if you have a `data` variable with parsed XML data, you could flatten it with this `flatten-xml` function:

```clj
(flatten-xml data)
; => ("2015-06-20T21:00Z/2015-06-21T21:00Z" "PT1H" "1" "0.0" "2" "0.0" "3" "0.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to do it:

```
 (defn flatten-bfs [{:keys [attrs content]}]
  (loop [ret [], queue (into clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY content)]
    (if (seq queue)
      (let [{attrs :attrs children :content} (peek queue)]
       (recur (if (nil? (:v attrs)) ret (conj ret (:v attrs)))  (into (pop queue) children))
       )
      ret
      )
    )
  )
```

Comment: Consider following [Clojure community coding style conventions](https://github.com/bbatsov/clojure-style-guide), it'll greatly omprove readability of your code. Fore example, [here is a re-formatted version of your function](https://gist.github.com/lbeschastny/105502ea94682afff68c).